# Euler's series proof

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\begin{array}{l}
 {S_n} = 1 + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 2}} + \frac{1}{{3 \cdot 3}} + ...\frac{1}{{n \cdot n}} <  \\ 
 1 + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 1}} + \frac{1}{{3 \cdot 2}} + ... +  + \frac{1}{{n \cdot (n - 1)}} =  \\ 
 1 + \left( {1 - \frac{1}{2}} \right) + \left( {\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{3 \cdot 2}}} \right) + ... + \left( {\frac{1}{{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{n}} \right) \\ 
  = 1 + 1 - \frac{1}{n} < 2 \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Can you please explain the equality of rows two and three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-(n-1)}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$
A way of arriving at this result is called *partial fraction expansion*, and is a very useful technique to recognise.

Comment: So, there must be a typo. $${1 \over {3*2}} \ne {1 \over 2} - {1 \over {3*2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple, since 
$\frac{1}{{n \cdot (n - 1)}}=\frac{1}{{n-1}}-\frac{1}{{n }}$.